# Accessing Windows Fileshares with a domain user account in Python

Tags: python, active-directory, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm working on a tool to automatically generate some documents and store them on a file share. I've got a service account that has the required access, and I'm trying to see how best to specify that I want to use that account when accessing the fileshare.

Here's my relevant test code for attempting to access my test files:

```
database_path = "\\\\testserver\\testfile.txt"
try:
    with open(database_path, "r") as testfile:
        lines = testfile.readlines()
        print(lines)
        testfile.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Couldn't access the test file.")
```

I'm running this through gitlab via a linux runner so piggybacking off of an existing domain user account isn't an ideal solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply mount the fileshare on the Linux filesystem using cifs-utils and `mount`

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<win_share_user>,password=<password> //<WIN_SHARE_HOST>/<share_name> /mnt/my_share
```

Then in Python, just open the file you want, e.g. `open('/mnt/my_share/path/to/file')`

You'll need to install cifs-utils on your linux box:

`apt install cifs-utils` for ubuntu/debian or
`yum install cifs-utils` for fedora or
`apk add cifs-utils` for alpine

Alternatively, you can use any Python package supporting the samba (the underlying standard used by Windows) file sharing protocol, such as [fs.smbfs](https://pypi.org/project/fs.smbfs/).

```py
import fs
smb_fs = fs.open_fs('smb://username:password@SAMBAHOSTNAME:port/share')
```

Comment: You're the man. I totally forgot about SMB somehow. Thank you!